# Spring+Hibernate validation: throws Hibernate Exceptions and not Spring exceptions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

I have a simple project (details below) which has a Spring bean and uses HV are validation provider, used for method parameter validation.

Problem: When validation fails, it throws Hibernate exception (`org.hibernate.validator.method.MethodConstraintViolationException`). But I would expect it to throw Spring exception (`org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException`), since Spring is the wrapping interface. For all I know, I do not care who is the validation implementor and need to deal with only Spring defined classes.

Question 1: Is the above argument right and should it throw Spring exceptions?

Question 2: If Hibernate exception is the norm, how do I map it to a friendly message (could not find this info on Google)

**ProductManager.java:**

```
@Component
@Validated
public class ProductManager {

    public void createProduct(@Valid Product product) {

    }
}
```

**Product.java:**

```
public class Product {

    private int id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**Tester.java:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/META-INF/applicationContext.xml"})
public class Tester {

    @Autowired
    ProductManager productManager;

    @Test
    public void testCreateProduct() {
        Product p = new Product();

        try {
            productManager.createProduct(p);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**applicationContext.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gammay.example" />

    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
        <qualifier value="validator"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor"/>

</beans>
```

**Exception printed in Tester.java:**

> org.hibernate.validator.method.MethodConstraintViolationException: The
>   following constraint violations occurred:
>   [MethodConstraintViolationImpl [method=public void
>   com.gammay.example.core.ProductManager.createProduct(com.gammay.example.model.Product),
>   parameterIndex=0, parameterName=arg0, kind=PARAMETER, message=may not
>   be null,
>   messageTemplate={javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message},
>   rootBean=com.gammay.example.core.ProductManager@12e79d0,
>   rootBeanClass=class com.gammay.example.core.ProductManager,
>   leafBean=com.gammay.example.model.Product@92acdc, invalidValue=null,
>   propertyPath=ProductManager#createProduct(arg0).name,
>   constraintDescriptor=ConstraintDescriptorImpl{annotation=javax.validation.constraints.NotNull,
>   payloads=[], hasComposingConstraints=true,
>   isReportAsSingleInvalidConstraint=false, elementType=FIELD,
>   definedOn=DEFINED_LOCALLY, groups=[interface
>   javax.validation.groups.Default],
>   attributes={message={javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message},
>   payload=[Ljava.lang.Class;@7ce531,
>   groups=[Ljava.lang.Class;@1ab0086}}]]     at
>   org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:91)
>   ...

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the inner workings of spring's `MethodValidationInterceptor` there is a `private static class HibernateValidatorDelegate` within buildValidatorFactory. Spring is making the called to configure Hibernate's `HibernateValidator` which is doing the actual real validation, hence why it your seeing `org.hibernate.validator.method.MethodConstraintViolationException`